# Format OCR text annotation from Cloud Vision API in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am using the Google Cloud Vision API for Python on a small program I'm using. The function is working and I get the OCR results, but I need to format these before being able to work with them.

This is the function:

```
# Call to OCR API
def detect_text_uri(uri):
    """Detects text in the file located in Google Cloud Storage or on the Web.
    """
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
    image = types.Image()
    image.source.image_uri = uri

    response = client.text_detection(image=image)
    texts = response.text_annotations

    for text in texts:
        textdescription = ("    "+ text.description )
        return textdescription
```

I specifically need to slice the text line by line and add four spaces in the beginning and a line break in the end, but at this moment this is only working for the first line, and the rest is returned as a single line blob.

I've been checking the official documentation but didn't really find out about the format of the response of the API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are almost right there. As you want to slice the text line by line, instead of looping the text annotations, try to get the direct '**description**' from google vision's response as shown below.

```
def parse_image(image_path=None):
    """
    Parse the image using Google Cloud Vision API, Detects "document" features in an image
    :param image_path: path of the image
    :return: text content
    :rtype: str
    """

    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
    response = client.text_detection(image=open(image_path, 'rb'))
    text = response.text_annotations
    del response     # to clean-up the system memory

    return text[0].description
```

The above function returns a string with the content in the image, **with the lines separated by "\n"**

Now, you can add prefix & suffix as you need to each line.

```
image_content = parse_image(image_path="path\to\image")

my_formatted_text = ""
for line in image_content.split("\n"):
    my_formatted_text += "    " + line + "\n"
```

`my_formatted_text` is the text you need.