# Unable to get ocr text with google vision api

Tags: python, google-api, ocr, google-vision

I use google vision api to detect the ocr.

However, I got no ocr text.

On the other hand, I uploaded the image to `https://cloud.google.com/vision/` and got `DBR Weddings\n`.

Is it normal?

How should I correct my code?

Thank you very much.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import cv2
import base64
import ast

url = r'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1pjofUsy5V4v7DSVsRERw6S-Zo36hO1bZ'
feature_json_obj = [{'type': 'TEXT_DETECTION', 'maxResults': 100}]
img = Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get(url).content))
arr = cv2.cvtColor(np.asarray(img.convert('RGB'), dtype=np.uint8), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

content_json_obj = {'content': base64.b64encode(a_numpy.tostring()).decode('UTF-8')}
request_list = {'requests': [{'features': feature_json_obj, 'image': content_json_obj, 'imageContext': {'languageHints': "zh-TW"}}]}
req = requests.post(url='https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=my_key', data = str.encode(str(request_list)), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}).text
receive_data = req.encode(sys.stdin.encoding, "replace").decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
data = ast.literal_eval(receive_data)['responses'][0]['fullTextAnnotation']['text']#get google-vision result
```

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266531/format-ocr-text-annotation-from-cloud-vision-api-in-python/48267374#48267374

Comment: There is no text returned when using api.